# XmlDocument XSD Validation does not find error

Tags: c#, xml, validation, xsd, xmldocument

I build my XmlDocument in code.
Before returning it I want to validate it against an XSD defined in a file.

```
xmlDocument.Schemas.Add(null, "MySchema.xsd");
xmlDocument.Validate((sender, e) => {
    if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error) {
                // Write error to log
    }
});
```

There never occurs any error. Although I added an error to my XmlDocument for testing purposes.

Can anyone please tell me, what I have done wrong?

Edit:
My XSD starts like

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="MyRoot">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Things" type="Things"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:complexType name="Things">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Thing" type="Thing" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
```

...and so on. I do not think, that the rest is relevant for the problem.

At a breakpoint I copied the (first few lines of the ) InnerXml from my XmlDocument:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
        <MyRoot>
           <ThingsAndSomeStuffMakingItInvalid>
               <Thing>
```

... and so on.

Thanks
Max

Comment: You should show us also your XML / XSD.

Comment: Edited my Question: I added the beginning of my xsd and xml. I do not think that the inner details and the closing tags are relevant for my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is caused by the fact that in your XML file you're not referincing your "MySchema". So when trying to validate it, the validator won't know the XML file should be validated against that XML file.

Comment: I have no XML file here. I create an XmlDocument in memory. I try to add the schema in the line xmlDocument.Schemas.Add(null, "MySchema.xsd");

Comment: As you can see from your in memory xml, there is no schema reference in it. Check here: http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_howto.asp this is how a schema is referenced in an XML.

Comment: I see that. But how do I add a schema to an XmlDocument in code? I thought xmlDocument.Schemas.Add would do that?

Comment: Try not using null as parameter but the actual target name space.

Comment: Thanks for your namespace hint. I found my error: The xsd in my build output was not updated. Besides xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" it contained another namespace (I removed a while ago in the original file). When I used it from build output there was a namespace in XSD while there was no namespace in the XML. Unfortunately this problem did not rise an error - it just ignored the XSD.